# Firefox Addon using SDK HotKey not shown on sidebar Menu

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-sdk, hotkeys, firefox-sidebar

My extension is a sidebar. 
I've set a hotkey to open it (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>).
The keyboard shortcut works perfectly but is not shown next to its menu item.

What can I do to show the hotkey ?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by 'not shown' - please provide a lot more detail if you want an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to include a line in your sidebar.html file that shows the user what the hotkey is.

```
<span>Shortcut: alt+shift+c</span>
```

Comment: Ok, but overlay extensions displayed the shortcut on the sidebar menu... There is any solution to do this with the addon-sdk ?

Comment: Not that I know of. You'll just have to use HTML and CSS to style it in the same way.

Comment: Okay, I understand your answer. But, I don't want to display the shortcut on the sidebar .. But, I want to display it on the native sidebar menu (like the history sidebar, bookmarks, ...)